# Port forwarding with Modem and a router

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, modem

I have a modem/router using ADSL which is already provided by the ISP and i also have another router which is connected to my modem. I already have a static ip for my modem but i still cant port forward

already tried these following steps
-set port forwarding to my router from modem.
-set port forward from my router to my server unit.
-set static ip address to my server unit.

I still cant access my server using the public ip address, provided the required steps have been followed

Comment: Move your router to modem's DMZ. Move your server to router's DMZ. Of course, router and server addresses must be static. If fails then check firewalls on both modem and router.

Comment: How do i specifically do it? is it in the configuration of the router and the modem? By moving you mean telling the modem and router that i have these IP addresses to allow in the DMZ?

Comment: "Move to DMZ" means: set static IP to client, configure this address as DMZ in router settings. Now all external connection attempts (i.e. which are not answers to previously sent packets and do not contain according records in routing table) will be transmitted to the address which is set as DMZ address. Unwanted attempts may be restricted by both router's firewall and client's firewall. *How do i specifically do it?* Look for this in your modem/router documentation. The most NAT-routing devices have this setting. You have not specified the models in the question...

Comment: Okay now i get what you are trying to say. Thanks really appreciated very helpful. I think that's what i'm lacking. I'll post an update if i made it work. But does all modems and routers provide DMZ service? if so, does all allow for DMZ manipulation?

Comment: *does all modems and routers provide DMZ service?* No, of course. That's why I tell that the models of your devices must be specified.

Comment: but what if i buy my own ADSL modem, will it work for my ISPs connection? or is Mac address locked? so there would be no way i can use other modems other than theirs?

Comment: You MUST ask your ISP. Nobody else can answer.

Comment: i did a little research and found out that i can implement this by using PPPoe. What do you think is the best? putting my modem and router to bridge mode? or the DMZ?

Comment: Bridge mode == NAT off. It is not applicable in your case it seems. So use DMZ.

Comment: Okay will do sir, i'll be keeping in touch. I will try my best to solve this problem.

Comment: UPDATE. It seems that my modem doesnt have DMZ but my router does. Do i still have hope for this?

Comment: Modem - map ports to router. Router - server to its DMZ.

Comment: UPDATE. I now have a modem/router that supports DMZ. can i directly DMZ from the modem/router to pc right away? just for testing?

Comment: *can i directly DMZ from the modem/router to pc right away? just for testing?* Of course. Then, accessing modem's external IP from Internet you (moreover, everyone) will really access your PC... so test very-very quickly.

Comment: Is it possible to DMZ from modem to router then my router would just forward it to the server without using DMZ? just the basic Port Forward?

Comment: UPDATE. Still failed to connect to MS SQL server 2014